# How can I download a file from the Internet via Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

As mentioned in the title I need a command line that allows me to download a file in the background without installing any tool just cmd I found this one but it doesn't work in the background and Need a confirmation

```
C:\windows\explorer.exe https://www.website.com/file.zip
```

so how to make the magic happen? and is there another command that i need to add it to the above line like a confirmation !?

Comment: This question should be on SuperUser.

Comment: Yes, off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: But it is not a duplicate of the other link. The answer here is to use wget, while the answer there is about a batch file. I vote to reopen even though it is not right on Stack Overflow. I also flagged it to be moved to Super User.

Answer (score 11):

CMD doesn't have a built-in download command.  You can download a utility like [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), and get the file with

```
C:\> wget https://www.website.com/file.zip
```

PowerShell, which is built into every version of Windows 7 and above, does have a built-in command for downloading in `Invoke-Webrequest`

```
PS> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.website.com/file.zip' -OutFile 'c:\temp\file.zip'
```

You can invoke this in one line from CMD by using the following PowerShell.exe command line.

```
powershell -c "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.website.com/file.zip' -OutFile 'c:\temp\file.zip'"
```

Comment: so what about option B add a command of confirmation !!